# How to show custom toast below ActionBar

Tags: android, toast, android-actionbar-compat

How can I show a custom Toast just below ActionBar (compatible with API7)?

A method which creates the Toast is as follows:

```
public void showToast(Activity context, String text) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.popup);
    tv.setText(text);
    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0, Y);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();
}
```

Actually, in order to be able to call this method from any activity, I put it in my Application class. As I understand, I need to put Y (top offset) to toast.SetGravity(). But I have no idea how to get the correct top coordinate of activity's layout, which is "ActionBar bottom". Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Y would be the height of the ActionBar

Assuming you're using the appcompat library and you've not changed the ActionBar height this should work:

```
int Y = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.abc_action_bar_default_height);
```

Comment: This did not work for me, however I managed to obtain the heigh by doing the following: `int Y = getSupportActionBar().getHeight();`. Hope it helps :)

Comment: `Cannot resolve symbol abc_action_bar_default_height`

Answer (score 1):

```
TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
{
    actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

it gives actionbar height

Answer (score 0):

Use this class I've written:

```
public class TopToast
{
    private TextView m_tv = null;
    private Toast m_Toast = null;
    private Activity m_Activity = null;

    public TopToast(Activity activity)
    {
        m_Activity = activity;
        m_Toast = new Toast(m_Activity);
    }

    public void show(String text, int TextColor)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = m_Activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
        m_tv = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.popup);
        m_tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(m_Activity, TextColor));
        m_tv.setText(text);

        final TypedArray styledAttributes = m_Activity.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] { android.R.attr.actionBarSize });
        int Y = (int) styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
        styledAttributes.recycle();

        m_Toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START | Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0, Y);
        m_Toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        m_Toast.setView(layout);
        m_Toast.show();
    }

    // Call this if you wish to hide toast quickly (viz. from onPause of activity, so that if user closes activity quickly toast too will disappear)
    public void hide()
    {
        if (m_Toast!=null)
            m_Toast.cancel();

       if (m_tv!=null)
            m_tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

And xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu"/>
</LinearLayout>
```